# Avoid Python Unit Test Class to invoke tests on import while running via nosetests

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

I have a class called Test as follows

ViewTests.py

```
import unittest
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def testAddition(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def testAddition2(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

The unit test runs all fine. The issue is when I import this class for other implementations somewhere else like this, `from package import Tests` on import the test cases get invoked automatically.
Is there a way to avoid this.

I would like to import as this:

TestRunner.py

```
from ViewTests import Tests
def some_method():
    print "Testing"
```

In this case, When you execute this as `nosetests TestRunner.py`  It will result as `Ran 2 tests in 0.000s`. Which means only by importing ViewTests it gets implemented.

Comment: Is it the complete script contents? Or, do you have the `unittest.main()` call there?

Comment: @alecxe - I may want to use the testAddition method at a different place

Comment: Please update the complete script that you are importing

Comment: No, I mean the `.py` file that has Tests class

Comment: The .py file is as simple as the first piece of code in the quesiton

Comment: Is package a folder? If so, can you paste its `__init__.py` ?

Comment: I just cannot reproduce this behaviour with your code snippet (corrected to at least make it executable).

Comment: Hi Kousick, just defining the class (and importing) it in another script does not cause it to get invoked, there must be something else going on? Are you 100% sure that is the complete code for ViewTests.py ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar: I have made edits. I think you can reproduce this now. Use nosetests to run the script